# Pytorch Conditioned Dataloader

Tags: pytorch

Let’s say I have a dataloader which returns video samples where each video sample is of the following shape : [number_of_frames X 2048] (number of frames can vary from the following set : [60 , 80 , 100 , 120].

I want in each batch returned from the dataloader to have samples with the same number of frames.
for example if the batchsize=16 . I want batches of the following shape : [16 X 80 X 2048] , [16 X 60 X 2048]… 
I have tried to sort the data samples such that we will have continuous samples of the same lengths. but I don't think this is a good solution. 
Anyidea how to do it?
Thanks

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: Put the videos in different folders according to the number of frames. Would that be a solution?

Comment: @sfotiadis I have tried to sort the data samples such that we will have continuous samples of the same lengths. but I don't think this is a good solution

Comment: Can you explain in details the data you have and how you want to use them?